# How to monitor WGET download progress after closing SSH session

Tags: ssh, wget

I have started downloading my ISO's etc directly to my fileserver using `wget`. After I close the `ssh` session, how can I check back on the download process?

Scenario: I start the download, then shut down my computer. The next day I `ssh` into the server and want to see if the download is still active, complete or has been interupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of Googling, I found an answer with the discovery an app called Screen.

After installation on the server (`sudo apt-get install screen`), you SSH into the server and open a screen session on the server with `screen -S SESSION_NAME` (replacing SESSION_NAME with any name you like). Then you run WGET and once the download is running, exit the session with CTRL+a, then press d (to **d**etatch from the session. You can run multiple sessions (with different names) at the same time.

After re-login at a later date, you can check on your processes by SSHing into the server and reopening the screen session on the server with `screen -r SESSION_NAME` (to **r**econnect to the session).

Once the session is finished with, kill it with CTRL+a, then press k (to **k**ill the session).

It's like having a virtual terminal within your virtual terminal.

Comment: The screen has been refereed in first answer as well

Comment: You should award points to those that take time to answer your question, even if you find the answer on your own. That is the ethical code of S.O. and largely what the S.O. economy of points revolve around.

Answer (score 14):

If you run wget and close the terminal or terminate your ssh session , it will terminate the wget process too. You need to run wget and keep it running even after the session is closed.

For that purpose there are many tools.

```
   wget -bqc http://path-to-url/linux.iso
```

You will see a PID on screen:

Continuing in background, pid 12345.

Where,

```
-b : Go to background immediately after startup. If no output file is specified via the -o, output is redirected to wget-log.
-q : Turn off Wget’s output aka save disk space.
-c : Resume broken download i.e. continue getting a partially-downloaded file. This is useful when you want to finish up a download started by a previous instance of Wget, or by another program.
```

**The nohup command**

You can also use the nohup command to execute commands after you exit from a shell prompt. The syntax is:

```
   $ nohup wget -qc http://path-to-url/linux.iso &

   ## exit from shell or close the terminal ##
   $ exit
```

**The disown bash command**

Another option is to use the disown command as follows:

```
      $ wget -qc http://path-to-url/linux.iso &
      [1] 10685
      $ disown wget
     $ ps
        PID TTY          TIME CMD
        10685 pts/0    00:00:00 wget
        10687 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
        10708 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
     $ logout
```

**The screen command**

You can also use the screen command for this purpose.

Comment: I don't have the problem of wget halting after closing my ssh session. Until now, I can sudo-monitor the download by viewing the target folder in my file manager and seeing the file size grow. This however, doesn't say whether the download is still in progress (except for refreshing the view and seeing the file size jump) or if the download was interrupted and needs restarting.

Comment: http://fitnr.com/showing-file-download-progress-using-wget.html

Comment: Yet another way (just for completeness) would be `echo 'wget ...' | at 'now + 1 minute'` (on systems which run `atd` – some systemd-based ones don't do that anymore by default). In this way, there is no connection whatever between the download and the calling shell, since the download is started in one minute by the timed execution daemon.

Comment: These look like nice ideas. However they seen to be centred around providing an output that disappears once the terminal window is closed! I am looking to be able to jump back in after a NEW terminal session is started.

Comment: @AndrewHeath `ps aux | grep wget | grep -v grep` shows active wget processes. As for a way to check the progress percentage, if you start *without* `-q` and you used `nohup` then the progress will be printing in the `nohup.out` file.

Comment: @IjazAhmadKhan Does doing `wget -b` (without using `nohup`) keep it running even if the session is closed? I'm having trouble following.

Answer (score 5):

Go to download directory and type

```
tail -f wget-log
```

Comment: You should specify that this will only work if run in the background without the quiet parameter, but it is not a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use tmux (which is a bit like screen) but I think is easier to use.

```
sudo apt-get install tmux
tmux new -s <session-name>
```

then run you script in the session
press control + b + d to detach

when you want to get back the terminal simply do

```
tmux a
```

The advantage is that you can check back easily if anything has gone wrong but if you want to download lots of simultaneous files, maybe its easier to check the log