# How to run a program in a screen, redirect all output to a file and detach

Tags: linux, pipe, gnu-screen

Running a command in a screen and detaching is quite simple.

```
screen -S test -d -m echo "output of command that runs forever"
```

However I would also like to pipe all the output to a file for logging, how can run the following in a screen and detach.

```
echo "output of command that runs forever" &> output.log
```

Edit:

Just to clarify, I need this for a script so simple starting a screen and doing running the command and detaching is not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> screen -dmS workspace; screen -S workspace -X stuff $'ps aux > output-x\n'

I first create a detached session with the -d switch, I called my session workspace.  I then send my command to the same session with -X stuff, I am using $'', but you could also use double quotes, but have to do a control M instead of a \n, which I don't like so I normally use the method I described above.

After this piece of code runs, you will find the output-x with the list of processes, and also if you do a:

screen -ls

you will see the session has been detached.

Since you said you are going to be running a script.  You might want to have your script search for a detached session (I am using workspace), and if it exists send commands to that pre-existing session, instead of making a new session every time "screen -dmS sessionName" is ran, example is below:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    if ! ( screen -ls | grep workspace > /dev/null); then
       screen -dmS workspace;
    fi
    screen -S workspace -X stuff $'ps aux > output-x\n'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped. On slower vms I did have to add a sleep between the two commands for it to work reliably.

Comment: does this work if we wanted to monitor serial port, for e.g. `screen /dev/ttyUSB0`?

Comment: Which purpose of the `stuff` in the command? I tried to execute the command exactly and nothing happened. No log file was created and when I activated workspace there was no any output there. I tried it in macOS's Terminal.

Comment: @C0DEF52 it is an input buffer of a window.  You can search for that term in the manual page located [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html).  Were you running the script? Or were you just running that one line.  That one line connects to a screen session called workspace, and then stuffs a string as input to that window like you typed it, when you do a screen -ls you should see the session called workspace, and when you attach to that window you will see the input was indeed sent to a window, and there should be an output-x file created with the process list in it.

Comment: @NiteRain I tried one line and script in default macOS Terminal app. Here I recorded a video how I tried a single line variant: https://youtu.be/gpQHP3fZ8T4

Comment: @NiteRain actually I solved my problem inside the script which std out and err I wanted to mirror. I added `exec > >(tee -i logfile.log)` and `exec 2>&1` into it.

Answer (score 6):

You can wrap your command in an extra `bash` (or your actual shell) call and make redirection there:

```
$ screen -dm bash -c 'echo hello > ./out'
$ cat ./out
hello
```

From the `man screen`:

> -d -m   Start screen in "detached" mode. This creates a new session but doesn't attach to it. This is useful for system startup scripts.

## Naming a session

It may be suitable to name your background jobs to disambiguate them in the `screen -ls` and to attach if neccessary:

```
$ screen -S mysession -dm sleep 20
$ screen -ls
8431.mysession  (10/04/2021 12:47:58 PM)    (Detached)

# attach
$ screen -r mysession
```

## How to pass arguments

Parameterization may be a hassle though. The arguments being passed are fed into `bash` starting with `$0` -- note the `ignore_me_arg`:

```
# note the outer-most quotes to be single -- we don't want them to
# be expanded on the caller's side, but on the callee's one

$ screen -dm bash -c 'echo $1 > ./out' ignore_me_arg hello
$ cat ./out
hello
```

As a final example, let's say you have a program `super_script` that does some stuff and prints all its arguments to `stdout` (as `echo` would do). You want to call it inside `screen`, make a redirection, and do all that jazz with different sets of arguments. Then this should do:

```
$ screen -dm bash -c 'super_script "$@"  > ./out.1' arg0 arg1
$ screen -dm bash -c 'super_script "$@"  > ./out.2' arg0 arg1 arg2
... wait for screen's to finish
$ cat out.1
arg1
$ cat out.2
arg1
arg2
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `disown` or `nohup`

usage:
[How to monitor WGET download progress after closing SSH session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252158/how-to-monitor-wget-download-progress-after-closing-ssh-session/252161#252161)