# how to force `screen -L` to overwrite log?

Tags: logs, gnu-screen

I want to run some long calculation jobs in the background. I choose `screen`. However I found screen didn't accpet redirection. for example

```
screen -dmS name ls>ls.dat
```

won't generate `ls.dat`.

Fortunately, `screen -L` will output screen's log to a file. However, what it does is to append to previous log file, even if I `pkill screen` and start a fresh new screen.

Is there a way to force it to overwrite the previous log file when starting a new screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can force screen to overwrite the log.  It logs to `screenlog.%n` by default, where `%n` is the screen window number (so each window has it's own log).  If that file exists, it appends to it.

However, you can tell `screen` to use a different filename, including a timestamp, so you'll get a new log file each time, but you'll then need to manage the old logs.

In `.screenrc` you can put the following line,

`logfile /path/to/log/screenlog-%n-%Y%m%d-%c:%s`

to create log files that include the window number (`%n`) and the year, month, date, and time.

Alternatively, you could create a `bash` alias that deletes the log file before running screen, for example,

`alias screen='rm /path/to/log; screen'`

If you want to affect `screen` log files in the current directory, just remove `/path/to/log/` from the commands above.

Lastly, depending on what you're trying to achieve, the Linux tool `script` might be more useful than just logging in `screen`.  `man script` for more information.

Comment: Hi, EightBitTony. Thank you for answering. But generally, we start screen in different folder(corresponding to different job), the logfiles are then in different folder.

Comment: You can drop the path parts from the above and it'll use the current directory.

Comment: This works! Thank you very much. But do you know why redirection is not working in screen command? for example, `screen -dmS xxx ls>ls.dat`

Comment: `screen` doesn't send output to `stdout` in that way, so you can't redirect `screen`'s output, that's why it has a logging option.

Comment: So you mean your method probably the only way? I just saw this http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257859/31374 ? However I can't reproduce the result, don't know why

Comment: That question runs a single command within screen and sends the output from that command to a file. That's not what your question asked.  If you have another query, or you're trying to solve a different issue, mark this as accepted and ask that in a new question, or, edit the question to reflect what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I updated my post. I think these two questions closely related. So I make it one. And I guess you know both answers : )

Comment: There is already a question on the site which discusses how to redirect within screen, you pointed to it - so this will just get closed as a duplicate.  The problem you have is solved by one or the other, but they are not answers to the same question.

Comment: Ok, I'll accept yours. Thank you very much :)