# Why %H%M%S is not working in .screenrc?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, date, time

According to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280152/31374), I can rename logfile of screen with date to avoid logfile appending problem

But `%c` used in that answer contains a colon, like `19:00`. Since I have to sync files with windows, while windows won't accept colon in filename.

So according [Linux: Bash Get Time](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bash-get-time/), I tried

```
logfile ./screenlog-%n-%H%M%S
```

But, I got different inteperation. `%H` becomes the name of logging node, `%M` becomes Apr, %S becomes 0S

What is wrong? How to get correct date and time in `.screenrc` ?

Comment: `:` is called a 'colon', not a 'semi-colon'.     `;` is the semi-colon.

Answer (score 2):

In "Bash Get Time", they describe the arguments to `date` command. `screen` uses a similar format, but the arguments are different. Check out the ["String Escapes" section of the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#String-Escapes) (also available in the man page) for details.

As far as I can see, there's no way to achieve what you want. Perhaps seconds (`%s`) will suffice?

Comment: Thank you very much. That is the list I am looking for. But is there really no way to manipulate the filename to delete the semicolon?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, there's no way to do that with Screen. You might be able to work around that by creating symbolic or hard links ("log.141532" → "log.14:15:32") and syncing those instead of the original files. `perl-rename --link-only 's/://g' log.*` will help you here.