# Why does this screen session exit when the command is finished?

Tags: linux, terminal, pipe, gnu-screen, stdout

I know `screen -dmS mysession command` to start a screen, launch a command and detach. When we need to redirect the stdout to a file, this works: (see [How to run a program in a screen, redirect all output to a file and detach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257845/how-to-run-a-program-in-a-screen-redirect-all-output-to-a-file-and-detach))

```
screen -dmS mysession bash -c 'ls > test.txt'      # simple example
```

However at the end, the screen session doesn't stay, we cannot do `screen -r mysession`, it doesn't exist anymore in `screen -ls`.

Question: in a one-liner, how to **start a screen session, launch a command, detach, redirect stdout to a file (like `> test.txt`) but don't automatically exit the screen session** when finished?

Linked question: [How to prevent "screen -dmS sessionName program.sh" from disappearing after program.sh finishes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960357/how-to-prevent-screen-dms-sessionname-program-sh-from-disappearing-after-prog)

Comment: This probably depends on what you want to achieve with this setting. The screen session ends because the bash you invoked terminates after the command (`ls > text.txt`) exits. But so does the input to your `test.txt`, so the question is - do you want the output of all further commands you would then interactively want to enter at the bash prompt to also appear in `test.txt`, or are you satisfied with just the output of the `ls` command ending up there, and simply want to have an open screen session available?

Comment: @AdminBee I want to be able to see for example the error log (stderr) that would not be saved to test.txt. For example this works thanks to your link `screen -dmS mysession bash -c 'ls -laW > test.txt; exec bash'`: `ls -laW` does an error, and we can see it when doing `screen -r mysession`. Great! Only remaining problem: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/703246/why-are-keystrokes-not-intercepted-after-reattaching-a-screen-dms-session-bash

Answer (score 4):

Using "bash -c" results in a non-interactive shell. You're creating a process tree as such:

```
screen───bash───ls
```

When `ls` finishes, `bash` has no further process and no further input and finishes also.

Thus `screen` finishes.

To do what you want to do, you'd need to start a interactive shell first.

```
screen -dmS session bash
```

Then input your commands into the screen session using screens `stuff` command.

```
screen -S session -p 0 -X stuff "ls > test.txt^M"
```

The `^M` acts like a newline.

You'd need to quit the shell using `exit^M` or the likes afterwards.

You can just combine all of into a one-liner afterwards IE

```
screen -dmS session bash && screen -S session -p 0 -X stuff "ls > test.txt^M"
```

Honestly I think for what you're trying todo however its probably better to avoid `screen` entirely and just disown whatever process it is you want to work on.

```
ls > test.txt & disown %1
```

This will do the same thing without all the extra cogs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The solution `screen -dmS session_name sh -c 'command > test.txt; exec bash'` (from the duplicate question) seems good too!

Comment: To me it seems that using screen logging feature instead of redirection might be helpful here too: `screen -L` will put all displayed stuff into `screenlog.0` instead. This might be useful and can be combined with `-dmS` features.