# Stay connected while executing a remote WGET command?

Tags: wget, remote, putty, telnet

I use Putty to remotely login into SERVER 1 and issue a WGET to another SERVER 2 to make a backup of a large directory.

My question is, do I have to stay connected while this process occcurs? Or, is it enough to simply exectute the WGET command and all the files will copy over, even if I disconnect?

If I do have to stay connected, how can I configure things so I don't have to stay connected?

Comment: Related: [How to monitor WGET download progress after closing SSH session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252158)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `screen`/`tmux` or run wget in background (`-b` option)

Answer (score 0):

Using `wget -bc` should work. By the way, if you want your job to keep running after you disconnect to the remote server, `nohup COMMAND >log 2>err &` might be a good idea.